# Wildcard in URL while using wget

Tags: shell, wildcard, wget

I am trying to copy entire file from S3 to HDFS through shell using below wild command:

```
wget https://export.xyz.com/Disabilities/*/*/*/*_0620.csv.zip
```

I am getting error:  ***ERROR 404: Not Found***
When I am using URL of one specific file, able to copy.

Please let me know how can I use wildcard in URL.

Comment: If you **really* * would type the command in the shell in exactly the same way you posted it, the shell would write an error message such as _No such file or directory_, because it tries to match your wildcards against your file system. Also, it is unclear to me what you mean by _using wildcards in an URL_, i.e. what you expect wget to do with an URL containing asterisks. It can forward it to the webserver of course, but then, what should the web server do?

Comment: @user1934428 The command to download one file is "wget https://export.xyz.com/Disabilities/state/city/MMYY/file_0620.csv.zip" but I need to download for all states, all cities and all months, so I used *.

Comment: I don't have much experience with `wget`, but where do you conclude from, that you can use wildcards in a https URL? The only possibility I find the use of wildcards in the wget manual is with ftp URLs. Maybe you are interested in doing a [recursive download](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Using wildcards is only applicable where all possibilities are already known:

- In a shell the operating system already knows all files of a directory: issuing `ls *.log` only works because this can be matched against all filenames that occur.
- In SQL the DBMS already knows all table columns and all data rows of the tables: issuing `SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%Rogers'` only works because all table's column names are already available, and because the filter can be matched against all rows that exist.
- In a regular expression the text to be operated on is already everything that needs to be known: searching for `p+` only works because its parts can be matched against i.e. `opposing forces`.

A uniform resource locator (URL) can never have wildcards, because then it wouldn't be uniform anymore. How should WGET (or any other HTTP client) should know which possibilities can be filled into a potential wildcard placeholder? Let alone know that `*` is by you meant as a wildcard and not a literal part of the URI? You're basically asking for "which URLs exist in the internet" and I wonder which answer you expect.

You have to come up with all permutations **yourself**, i.e. a list of all URLs that WGET can then process:

```
https://export.xyz/Disabilities/NY/NYC/0620/file_0620.csv.zip
https://export.xyz/Disabilities/NY/NYC/0720/file_0620.csv.zip
https://export.xyz/Disabilities/NY/NYC/0820/file_0620.csv.zip
```

In doubt, this list can be very big and contain URLs that indeed don't exist (and logically never will), as it will simply come out as HTTP status 404 then - all you will waste is a tiny bit of traffic and time.

Answer (score 0):

wget -r --no-parent -A '*_0620.csv.zip' https://export.xyz.com/Disabilities/

may work, I'm not 100% sure. -A sets the list of acceptable arguments, you may also have to accept directory patterns as well.